# Protractor and Appium always starting chrome

Tags: protractor, appium

I am trying to run the Protractor tests using Appium on iOS Simulator / Genymotion Android Emulator. For this question, let's stick to the iOS, shall we?

1. I've followed the steps on Protractor page [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md).
2. you will notice the URL to Appium installation doesn't work so [here](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/blob/master/docs/mobile.md) is the correct one.
3. Basically, you just have to `webdriver-manager update --ios`
4. Run `webdriver-manager start --ios` which will automatically start appium
5. Protractor config file:

`

```
'use strict';

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

  capabilities: {
    app: '/Users/aaa/Projects/bbb/platforms/ios/build/emulator/mobileCRM.app',
    browserName: 'safari',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '9.3',
    deviceName: 'IPad Simulator',
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:3000',


  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['./test/protractor/**/*.js'],

  /* configuring wd in onPrepare
   * wdBridge helps to bridge wd driver with other selenium clients
   * See https://github.com/sebv/wd-bridge/blob/master/README.md
   */
  onPrepare: function () {
    var wd = require('wd'),
      protractor = require('protractor'),
      wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
    wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
  }
};
```

`

6. Start the protractor as: `./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js`

Expected?
Should start iOS simulator,

What happens?
Protractor tests are ALWAYS starting in Chrome. So, what am I doing wrong?

Bonus:
`

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager status     
[13:01:05] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 2.53.1 [default] [last]
[13:01:05] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.26 [default] [last]
[13:01:05] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.12.0 [default] [last]
[13:01:05] I/status - appium version available: 1.6.0 [default] [last]
[13:01:05] I/status - android-sdk is not present
```

`

Comment: Did you see the notes at the bottom?  `baseUrl is localhost (not 10.0.2.2)`.

Comment: Hi @cnishina and thank you for your comment. I am now really unsure If I haven't already tried that. Will check and report immediately what I've found.

Comment: Hi @cnishina, you can create new answer, It was really that. -.-

Comment: Oh neat! I did not leave it as an answer (previously) since I have not tried Appium with Protractor yet. I am glad this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the [Setting Up Protractor with Appium - iOS / Safari](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md#setting-up-protractor-with-appium---iossafari) section, it notes the following:

```
baseUrl is localhost (not 10.0.2.2)
```